# C++ fstream read and write positions not aligned

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I'm writing a program to search through a file for a name, then overwrite some numbers after that name. My current approach is to read from an `fstream` until the name is found, then use the same `fstream` to overwrite the numbers after that point. However, the cursor position seems wrong. Here's a test program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string name;
    std::fstream file("test.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);
    while (file >> name) {
        if (name == "Jason") {
            file << "A";
            break;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

When test.txt contains only one line, the output seems to be correct; the 'A' is right after 'Jason'

test.txt:

```
                      Jason -1395354120                    0
```

result:

```
                      JasonA-1395354120                    0
```

However, when there are multiple lines, the 'A' gets written to the middle of the number instead:

test.txt:

```
                      Jason -1395354120                    0
                        Bob  1266020048                    0
                      Jason -1395354120                    0
                        Bob  1266020048                    0
                      Jason -1395354120                    0
                        Bob  1266020048                    0
```

result:

```
                      Jason -139A354120                    0
                        Bob  1266020048                    0
                      Jason -1395354120                    0
                        Bob  1266020048                    0
                      Jason -1395354120                    0
                        Bob  1266020048                    0
```

I'd like it to always write starting immediately after the name. How can I fix this?

Edit: If I replace `file << "A";` with `std::cout << file.tellg() << " " << file.tellp() << std::endl;` it shows that the write and read positions are both at 37, which is where the A appears in the 2nd example. I'm confused about this since I thought the >> operator should have stopped reading after "Jason", which should be 31.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the seekg() function in order to start at a position:

```
file.seekg(5, ios::beg); 
//The first parameter is the position, second is you are specifying if it is the beginning or end
```

Comment: I want to search for a name whose line number might not be known, so I'll need to read the file anyways. I thought the >> operator stops at whitespace, so why doesn't it do that in my example?

Comment: It looks like it is just adding 'A' at the very end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Jason, I tried your code and it gives me different results:

test.txt:

```
 Jason -1395354120                    0
```

result:

```
 Jason -1395354120                    0
A
```

test.txt:

```
 Jason -139A354120                    0
   Bob  1266020048                    0
 Jason -1395354120                    0
   Bob  1266020048                    0
 Jason -1395354120                    0
   Bob  1266020048                    0
```

result:

```
 Jason -139A354120                    0
   Bob  1266020048                    0
 Jason -1395354120                    0
   Bob  1266020048                    0
 Jason -1395354120                    0
   Bob  1266020048                    0
A
```

In other words, the code is not finding "Jason" and just adding the "A" at the end. Maybe you could try to include the `file << "A";` command inside a conditional, to see how the programme is working

EDIT: this works for me:

```
while (name != "Jason")
    {
        if (!(file >> name))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... For me it doesn't add A at the end. I replaced `file << "A";` with `std::cout << file.tellg() << " " << file.tellp() << std::endl;` and could see that both the read and write positions were 37 for the 2nd example.

Comment: I think the problem is that the `while` loop executes the `file >> name` command one last time to check the condition. My suggestion is keep only `name != "Jason"` in the `while` condition and `file >> name` inside the body. You will also need to check for the end of the file and add a `break;` command to quit the loop.

Comment: I changed the code to check for the match inside the loop body, but the result is still the same.

Comment: I edited my answer above with a solution that (at least for me) is working as intended, for both single and multiple line input.